# complex Joins to find sequential pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a file with the following first column value

```
+-----------+--------+
|  IDcolumn |  value |
+-----------+--------+
|         1 | A27    |
|         2 | A28    |
|         3 | A28    |
|         4 | A27    |
|         5 | A28    |
|         6 | A27    |
|         7 | A28    |
|         8 | A28    |
+-----------+--------+
```

I have had to put each A27 and A28 in their own table using SSIS and put an identity column but what I want to do is only bring back only where there is 2 occurrences of A28 after the A27

I am currently using `TableA27.IDcolumn in ( TableA28.IDcolumn + 1, TableA28.IDcolumn + 2)` but this will bring back the A28 which only occurs once where I need it to only bring A28's where it occurs twice.

Comment: I'm confused by your question. You provide sample data with two columns yet the first sentence claims it's the "first column value". W/R/T your business logic, could you explain that a bit better? ID 1 is an a27 and has two A28s after it so it should be in. ID 4 is an A27 and has two A28s after it (ID 5 and ID 7). Should we infer there is a business rule that indicates the A28s need to be pinned between A27s and/or end of file? Do you need a general purpose solution or will it only ever be A27 and A28? Given the above data, what should your output be in each table?

Comment: Yes you are correct in inferring that two row of A28 should be after an A27. I want the output to only show only the rows that have two A28 after an A27. So basically the output should be row 1,2,3,6,7,8. Missing out row 4 and 5 as only 1x A28 is after the A27

Comment: Not quite,  the answer below below didn't work,  but i think i got parts of it using lag and lead and a bit of case statement to verify what position they are in but I'm sure there are better ways